# Push view with data from asynchronous callback

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigation

I'm trying to find a viable way to handle navigation with data that has been returned from an asynchronous callback.

Consider the following example. The button in `NavigationExampleView` is triggering some async method on a separate object, `NavigationExampleViewModel` in this case. The returned data form the method, should then be *pushed on the navigation stack* in a `UserView`. A `NavigationLink` seems to be the way to archive this, but I can't find a way to get hold of a non-optional value of the data that I need to present.

```
struct User: Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
}

protocol API {
    func getUser() -> AnyPublisher<User, Never>
}

struct NavigationExampleView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var vm: NavigationExampleViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button("Get User") {
                vm.getUser()
            }
            NavigationLink.init(
                destination: UserView(user: ???),
                isActive: ???,
                label: EmptyView.init
            )
        }
    }
}

class NavigationExampleViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLoading = false
    @Published var pushUser: User?
    
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    let api: API
    init(api: API) { self.api = api }
    
    func getUser() {
        isLoading = true
        cancellable = api.getUser().sink { user in
            self.pushUser = user
            self.isLoading = false
        }
    }
}

struct UserView: View, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let user: User
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(user.name)
    }
}
```

**Questions:**

1. How do I get hold of the data to present as a non-optional value in the view?
2. What should I use as a binding to control presentation?

A way I can almost archive this is with the view modifier `.sheet(item: Binding<Identifiable?>, content: Identifiable -> View)`, like this:

```
struct NavigationExampleView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var vm: NavigationExampleViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button("Get User") {
                vm.getUser()
            }
        }.sheet(item: $vm.pushUser, content: UserView.init)
    }
}
```

How can archive the same for pushing the view onto the navigation stack, instead of presenting it as a sheet?

Comment: I would give the UserView multiple states it can be in such as "Not Loaded", "Loading", "Loaded". Then pass the API publisher directly to the userView and .onAppear { API.getUser }. So when the UserView appears, it will immediately begin loading and will displaye the data when the api returns it. It is explained very well here: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/handling-loading-states-in-swiftui/

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem :/ What if the specific view that should be pushed depend on the data thats returned. For instance, if I wanted to present some specific view for a user that is an admin and present some completely different view for a user that is not.

Comment: Make an async User-container view, like in my comment above. Then make two other view structs (Non-Admin and Admin). The container view will determine if the user is an admin or not and will pass the data along and display to the appropriate userview (Admin or NonAdmin)

Comment: I need to push the view once loading is done.

Comment: If you want to do something like that you'll have to do some extra working making a custom binding of some sort to use with a sheetCoverView. I dont think that is a good design pattern. The user will be confused if they click something expect and action to occur and nothing happens until the data is loaded. Take "Apple Music" for example.  When clicking on an album, the view is presented immediately and the album is shown when it loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the `if let` method from *@pawello2222*'s answer, I've created this `ViewModifier` that let's you push a View to the Navigation Stack. It follows the same pattern as the [`.sheet` modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/slider/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:)).

```
import SwiftUI

private struct PushPresenter<Item: Identifiable, DestinationView: View>: ViewModifier {
    
    let item: Binding<Item?>
    let destination: (Item) -> DestinationView
    let presentationBinding: Binding<Bool>
    
    init(item: Binding<Item?>, onDismiss: (() -> Void)? = nil, content: @escaping (Item) -> DestinationView) {
        self.item = item
        self.destination = content
        
        presentationBinding = Binding<Bool> {
            item.wrappedValue != nil
        } set: { isActive in
            if !isActive && item.wrappedValue != nil {
                onDismiss?()
                item.wrappedValue = nil
            }
        }
    }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            content
            NavigationLink(
                destination: item.wrappedValue == nil ? nil : destination(item.wrappedValue!),
                isActive: presentationBinding,
                label: EmptyView.init
            )
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    
    /// Pushed a View onto the navigation stack using the given item as a data source for the View's content.  **Notice**: Make sure to use `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` on the parent `NavigationView` otherwise using this modifier will cause a memory leak.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - item: A binding to an optional source of truth for the view's presentation. When `item` is non-nil, the system passes the `item`’s content to the modifier’s closure. This uses a `NavigationLink` under the hood, so make sure to have a `NavigationView` as a parent in the view hierarchy.
    ///   - onDismiss: A closure to execute when poping the view of the navigation stack.
    ///   - content: A closure returning the content of the view.
    func push<Item: Identifiable, Content: View>(
        item: Binding<Item?>,
        onDismiss: (() -> Void)? = nil,
        content: @escaping (Item) -> Content) -> some View
    {
        self.modifier(PushPresenter.init(item: item, onDismiss: onDismiss, content: content))
    }
}
```

And then use it like so:

```
struct NavigationExampleView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var vm: NavigationExampleViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Get User") {
            vm.getUser()
        }
        .push(item: $vm.pushUser, content: UserView.init)
    }
}
```

Be sure to keep your implementing view in a `NavigationView` for the `push` to take effect.

**Edit**

I found an issue with this solution. If using a reference type as the binding `item`, the object will not get deinitialised on dismiss. It seems like the `content` is holding a reference to the `item`. The Object will only the deinitialised once a new object is set on the binding (next time a screen is pushed).

This is also the case for *@pawello2222*'s answer, but not an issue when using the `sheet` modifier. Any suggestions on how to solve this would be much welcomed.

**Edit 2**

Adding `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` to the parent `NavigationView` removes the memory leak for some reason. See answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66537672/2299801) for more details.

Using the `if-let`-method caused the push view transition to stop working. Instead pass `nil` to the `NavigationLink`s `destination` when the data is not pressent. I've updated `ViewModifier` to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `if-let` to unwrap the optional `vm.pushUser`. Then, create a custom binding to map `Binding<User?>` to `Binding<Bool>`:

```
struct NavigationExampleView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var vm: NavigationExampleViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button("Get User") {
                vm.getUser()
            }
            if let user = vm.pushUser {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: UserView(id: "<id>", user: user),
                    isActive: binding,
                    label: EmptyView.init
                )
            }
        }
    }
    
    var binding: Binding<Bool> {
        .init(
            get: { vm.pushUser != nil },
            set: { if !$0 { vm.pushUser = nil } }
        )
    }
}
```

Alternatively, use it *inline*:

```
if let user = vm.pushUser {
    NavigationLink(
        destination: UserView(id: "<id>", user: user),
        isActive: .init(get: { vm.pushUser != nil }, set: { if !$0 { vm.pushUser = nil } }),
        label: EmptyView.init
    )
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me :/ The detail view is never pushed. I've tried printing the return values from the binding, the getter is returning `true` but still no view is pushed. Did you try this out?

Comment: @Wiingaard Yes, it works for me - Xcode 12.4, iOS 14.4. What is your environment?

Comment: Sorry man, I tested this again and it worked.. I must have had some other issue in the app I was testing it in. I've wrapped your method up in a nice little ViewModifier that follows the same pattern as the `sheet` modifier. I'm posting an answer now.. Thanks! :)